# Prosodylab Aligner

Tags: python, yaml

Can someone that uses this tool give me a step by step manual. while I follow the available youtube manual and others on the Github I have still problems. when I want to run `aligner.py` I have the error

```
from utilities import opts2cfg, mkdir_p, \
  File "/home/mary/Desktop/htk/Prosodylab-Aligner/aligner/utilities.py", line 8, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
```

Is there any way to fix it? I try to install yaml but it seems impossible

Answer (score 0):

The module should be install as `pyaml`. You can use `pip` to install Python packages. In your case this will be your installation command.

`pip install pyaml`